# Use custom image for icon "“mdpi” and ”hdpi” AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio, icons

So basically I have my own custom icon I have made for my application and I know how to set it via the android manifest but do I have to resize the images my self or will android studio do that for me or am I asking to much? thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio **doens't resize** the images.

You have to create yourself the images for all densities.
It can be useful an [external tool](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-generic.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&size=24&padding=8&color=33b5e5%2C100&name=ic_example) provided by ROman Nurik.

In `AndroidManifest` you **don't have** to specify the folder.
You have to use

```
 <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```

Answer (score 0):

Android stuido will not resize your images you should have different images for different resolution and add them in drawable folder accordingly.

Yo can use [Android Assets Studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/) for making some basic icons or you can also use different [plugins](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7647?pr=) for creating images.